# ¿Cómo setear un valor por defecto a mi select mediante jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quiero setear un valor por default cuando mi formulario se abra en mi select.

Tengo un formulario que comparte la funcionalidad de insertar y modificar. Entonces tengo dentro de un if un parámetro para saber qué acción realizar y es ahí donde introduzco mi valor por default.

Forma 1:

```
$('select option[value="0"]').attr("selected", true);
```

Forma 2:

```
$("#selClaveR").val("Seleccionar");
```

Pero ninguna de esas dos hace que mi select se ponga como seleccionado su valor.

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343566/set-select-option-selected-by-value

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Estimadisimo, le dejo dos opciones, una utilizando la última librería de JQuery y la seguna utilizando javascript puro, sin necesidad de importar nada.

Con JQuery 3.2.0

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="opciones">
    <option value ="1">Casa</option>
    <option value ="2">Auto</option>
    <option value ="3">Moto</option>
    <option value ="0">Seleccione un elemento</option>
    <option value ="4">Castillo</option>
    <option value ="5">Mall</option>
    <option value ="6">Avión</option>
    </select>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-JAW99MJVpJBGcbzEuXk4Az05s/XyDdBomFqNlM3ic+I="
      crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script>
    //Esta es la función que una vez se cargue el documento será gatillada.
    $(function(){
        $("#opciones").val('0')
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Sin ninguna librería (old School)

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<select id="opciones">
<option value ="1">Casa</option>
<option value ="2">Auto</option>
<option value ="3">Moto</option>
<option value ="0">Seleccione un elemento</option>
<option value ="4">Castillo</option>
<option value ="5">Mall</option>
<option value ="6">Avión</option>
</select>
<script>
    document.ready = document.getElementById("opciones").value = '0';
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Notese que la opción cero, que es la que dice seleccione un elemento, está en medio, por lo que si se quita el código javascript, no será cargado por defecto al principio.
Saludos.

Answer (score 7):

Pues así como lo tienes solo recoge el select y pásale un valor y listo.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#sel").val("3");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="sel">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

En el js debes aplicar la propiedad change despues de cargar el val

```
$("#tidservicio").val(datosViajes[1]);
$('#tidservicio').change();
```

Answer (score 2):

Ya tiene mucho tiempo esto, pero quizá a alguien le sirva aún:

```
$("#My_Select").val( "MiSeleccion" );
$("#My_Select").selectmenu('refresh', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Digamos que tienes:

```
<select id="opcion"><option></option>1<option></option>2<option>3</option></select>
```

en el js lo que tienes que haces es:

```
var elemento=2;
$("#opcion").puidropdown('selectValue', elemento);
```

Comment: ¿Por que no usas en tu ejemplo jQuery normal en lugar de una librería?

Answer (score 0):

Suelo tener este problema cuando uso alguna librería de estilo para mis selects pero lo soluciono aplicando esto.

```
        $("#Select").val( 'valor a seleccionar');
        $('#Select').selectpicker('render');
```

Complementando esta solución, es muy útil cuando se tiene un `<option>` sin valor declarado por medio del atributo value, para posteriormente restaurarlo a su valor inicial en un formulario:

```
<select id="miciudad">
   <option>Seleccione...</option>
   <option value="1">Mexico</option>
   <option value="2" selected>Guanajuato</option>
   <option value="3">Leon</option>
   .
   .
   .
</select>
```

---

(jquery) para seleccionar el primer :

```
$("#miciudad").val('Seleccione...');
```